# How to Split, insert and join video files together ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video 20 seconds long (00.20.00).
I want split it in 20 parts (part 1, part 2, pat 3,...part 20), then I want to insert between these sections a video effect **(part 1, video effect 1, part 2, video effect 1, part 3, video effect 1, .... par20)**.

I did not imagine the command to execute it, how can I do this?

=========================
I trial and error @Mulvya

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -i effect.mp4 -filter_complex
   "[0]split=20[v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14][v15][v16][v17][v18][v19][v20];
    [v1]trim=0:1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1t];
    [v2]trim=1:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2t];
    [v3]trim=2:3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3t];
    [v4]trim=3:4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4t];
    [v5]trim=4:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5t];
    [v6]trim=5:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v6t];
    [v7]trim=6:7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v7t];
    [v8]trim=7:8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v8t];
    [v9]trim=8:9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v9t];
    [v10]trim=9:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v10t];
    [v11]trim=10:11,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v11t];
    [v12]trim=11:12,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v12t];
    [v13]trim=12:13,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v13t];
    [v14]trim=13:14,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v14t];
    [v15]trim=14:15,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v15t];
    [v16]trim=15:16,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v16t];
    [v17]trim=16:17,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v17t];
    [v18]trim=17:18,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v18t];
    [v19]trim=18:19,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v19t];      
    [v20]trim=19:20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v20t];
    [v1t][1][v2t][1][v3t][1][v3t][1][v4t][1][v5t][1][v6t][1][v7t][1][v8t][1][v9t][1][v10t][1][v11t][1][v12t][1][v13t][1][v14t][1][v15t][1][v16t][1][v17t][1][v18t][1][v19t][1][v20t]concat=n=39:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] processed.mp4
```

.
.
.
[AVFilterGraph @ 03e5dae0] Too many inputs specified for the "concat" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Take some time to read [ask]. [Edit] your question specifying under which operative system  you are working (Windows,Linux,Osx...) and what you have tried till now. BTW You can use `ffmpeg`. For example [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks) you can find how to split a video in parts... then search about how you can put them together ([Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)). Start to build your strategy and ask for a specific problem.

Comment: Maybe you would find [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/) easier for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i myVideo.avi -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 1 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 -an video%d.avi`

Taken from [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148862/10525)

Will split a video into 20 segments, named video1.avi - video20.avi; Then we need to concernate the videos back together, with the videoEffect1.avi in between:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in ./video*.avi; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'" && echo "file '$PWD/videoEffect1.avi'"; done) -c copy output.avi`

More infomation at the [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Or, as one huge command:

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.avi -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 1 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 -an video%d.avi && ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in ./video*.avi; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'" && echo "file '$PWD/videoEffect1.avi'"; done) -c copy output.avi && rm -rf ./video[0-9]*.avi
```

Comment: Thanks @djsmiley2k: But i want  process treated at once  Split, insert and join video files together ?

Comment: Then simply put a && between the two processes; I've edited this in for you.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in one command, use

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i effect.avi -filter_complex
       "[0]split=20[v1][v2][v3]...[v20];
        [v1]trim=0:1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1t];
        [v2]trim=1:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2t];
        [v3]trim=2:3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3t];
        ...
        [v20]trim=19:20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v20t];
        [v1t][1][v2t][1][v3t][1]...[v19t][1][v20t]concat=n=39:v=1:a=0[v]"
-map [v] processed.mp4
```

I've assumed there's no audio.

In case, it's not clear, I've skipped writing out all the trim operations and all the inputs to the concat filter. Those should all be specified.

Comment: Hey @Mulvya : example: I have a video 1 hour long (01.00.00).
I want 30 seconds cut and insert a video effect?

Comment: The trim syntax is `trim=start:end` (in seconds). So, first 30 seconds is `trim=0:30`

Comment: So very long command ? I want to edit audio filter ?

Comment: I want to insert audio filter : "pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3,aeval='-val(0)':c=same,volume=1.7" how can I do this?

Comment: You can just add it as `-af pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3,aeval='-val(0)':c=same,volume=1.7` But the audio isn't split.

Comment: :I trial and error ===> [AVFilterGraph @ 03e5dae0] Too many inputs specified for the "concat" filter. Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument

Comment: The `n=` value should be the same as the number of inputs you supply.